# Make an array of strings of the names

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make an array of strings of the names

```
function namesOnly(arr) {

}
namesOnly([
  {
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
])
// expect: ["Angelina Jolie", "Eric Jones", "Paris Hilton", "Kayne West", "Bob Ziroll"]
```

So hope!

Comment: [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will help you for this task...

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Array​.prototype​.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
function namesOnly(arr) {
  return arr.map(i => i.name);
}
var res = namesOnly([
  {
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
])
console.log(res);
```

Though  I think `map()` is better fit here, you can also use `for...of` loop:

```js
function namesOnly(arr) {
  var names = [];
  for (let o of arr) 
    names.push(o.name);
  return names;
}
var res = namesOnly([
  {
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
])
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! What about for loop?

Comment: `for (let o of arr) res.push(o.name)`

Comment: @HoangDinh, you can also use for loop, but I think `map()` is better fit here:)

Comment: @Mamun Thanks so much! :D

Comment: @Mamun I have a syntax of map() method `arr.map(function (x)) {}`? . I want to write it. What need I do?

Comment: @HoangDinh Array.map takes a function in which what is returned in the function is the element(s) in the array.

Comment: @HoangDinh, `arr.map(function (x)) {}` is syntactically wrong, try `arr.map(function(x){ return x.name; })`....

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach and push to create your result

```
 function namesOnly(arr) {
       var result = [];
       arr.forEach(c=> { result.push(c.name); });

       console.log(result);
       return result;
    }
```

```js
function namesOnly(arr) {
   var result = [];
   arr.forEach(c=> { result.push(c.name); });
   
   console.log(result);
   return result;
}

namesOnly([
  {
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Array.map to compose a new array.

```
function namesOnly(arr) {
  return arr.map(element => { return element.name; });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function makeStrings(arr){
      let str = arr.map(function(s) {
        if(s.age >= 17) {
         return s.name + 'can go to The Matrix';
        } else if(s.age) {
          return s.name + 'is under age!';
      } 
   })
   return str;
 }
```

Comment: It is better to add some context to explain while sharing a code block. Furthermore, the question does not have any requirements related to ages.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26278312)